# iterate Jquery var list

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

items is a variable i used in below function...
items value is

`[{"daLevel":"DA0","daName":"Da Name 0"},{"daLevel":"DA1","daName":"Da Name 1"},{"daLevel":"DA2","daName":"Da Name 2"},{"daLevel":"DA3","daName":"Da Name 3"},{"daLevel":"DA4","daName":"Da Name 4"},{"daLevel":"DA5","daName":"Da Name 5"},{"daLevel":"DA6","daName":"Da Name 6"},{"daLevel":"DA7","daName":"Da Name 7"},{"daLevel":"DA8","daName":"Da Name 8"},{"daLevel":"DA9","daName":"Da Name 9"},{"daLevel":"DA10","daName":"Da Name 10"}]`

I need to display daName values in a select box as dropdown.
I am not able to get daName values from items var.
Any suggestion would be of gr8 help.
Thanks in advance

```
function notifyDa(excessId) {
alert("notified");
var html = "<table><tr><td align='center' colspan='2'> Excess Notification </td></tr><tr><td>Select DA Holder</td><td><select id='daList'>";
    var ctx = '${contextPath}';
    var queryUrl = ctx + "/excessList.htm?getDaList=true";
    $.ajax({
        url : queryUrl,
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "text",
        success : function(result) {
            alert(result);
            **var items = result;
            alert("items *** "+items);
            alert("items[0] *** "+items.daName[0]);**


            $('#notifyDiv').empty();
            $('#notifyDiv').html(html);

            $("#pop").click(function() {
                $("#notifyDiv").fadeIn(1000);
                if (!$("#notifyDiv").is(':visible')) {
                    return;
                }
            });

            $("#notifyDiv").css({
                left : ($(window).width() - $('#notifyDiv').width()) / 2,
                top : ($(window).width() - $('#notifyDiv').width()) / 7,
                position : 'absolute'
            });

        },
        error : function() {

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);  // as dataType is Text



items[0].daName;
```

Comment: try changing dataType to `json`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your **Datatype** to **JSON**, then you can use jQuery .each() function for parsing the JSON you are getting. Something like this:

```
$(items).each(function(index,element){
    alert(element.daName); 
});
```

This will iterate through all the objects and gives you the required fields.